# Mahout for unstructured data an advantage?

Tags: mahout

I have installed mahout and test run several examples; would it be safe to say that one of Mahout's advantages it being used for unstructured data (scalability aside)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No... most of the algorithms take fairly specifically structured input like vectors or user-item pairs. There are some tools for vectorizing text docs which are unstructured. But no I wouldn't call it a tool primarily for unstructured data.

Comment: Much obliged for the clarification...